# Asynchronous controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two web pages . In one page I am uploading some file and processing that data which takes lot of time to be completed. While on other page I am simply rendering the data on database. 
I have implemented this application in c# mvc.
My requirement is that once user upload the file the file processing start in background and user would be able to navigate other pages.

Can we achieve this through asynchronous controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that processing the data takes a lot of time. Using an asynchronous controller, you will free up the web server to serve other requests, however the request will complete in the same time as it would when invoked synchronously. (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you do not want your user to wait, add a job queue to your stack, tell the user that you've accepted the file and are processing it, and notify him when the operation completes.

There are many job queue implementations available in .NET, a concrete suggestion would depend on whether you're running on "full" .NET or .NET Core.

Comment: Would user be able to navigate other pages meanwhile request is being processed through asynchronous controller implementation?I have a doubt at this point. As per my understanding if user will navigate to other page then it would hit to another action method of other controller so processing will be stopped from asynchronous controller .

Comment: Correct. What you want to do cannot be done with asynchronous controllers. Some type of job queue is one option, or what Matt wrote above about having another service check the contents of a folder / database, and process, which would effectively be a kind of a job queue.

Answer (score 0):

Using async controllers won't do what you want here, although you should still use them as a first step. Async controllers will just free up the server threads so that more requests can be processed, without async any long running operations will block the threads they're using and stop other requests being processed. If there are enough long running threads then other client requests will get rejected.

You'll also (or instead) need to look into a different mechanism to process the file, for example the API action could just put the file in a folder and another (non-web service) process could monitor that folder and pick up new files to process. Alternatively you could look at queuing or message bus technology, this adds more complexity but also gives you safety around queue processing.

The other thing to consider is how you report validation issues or errors back to the uploading client, you could do some checks in the API action but you'll probably still need to consider how to notify clients when an error occurs during processing of a file. How you best do this will depend on your system.

Comment: Yes you are right that I can use another non web service to process further. But I was looking for any other option if possible. Please let me know if you could suggest any other implementation within same web project of dot net mvc. Also  , to answer your question how I will notify user about error is that I am sending mail to user in case of error and success